# Redux dispatcher fails to pass as a prop to child component

Tags: redux, react-redux

Both of the dispatchers below do not appear in the props object in the child (this.props shows only the "Hi" string that I pass in).

If I simply use them in App.js parent component though (as `this.props.<dispatcher()>`, they work.

```
    // App.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

import SelectDonation from './components/SelectDonation';

import {connect} from "react-redux";

import './semantic/dist/semantic.min.css';
import {Modal, Header, Button, Form} from "semantic-ui-react";

import Redux            from "redux";
import ReactRedux       from "react-redux";
import {log_to_console_function, set_donation_amount} from "./actions";
import store from "./reducer";


render() {
  return (
    <div className="App">    
        <SelectDonation ap="Hi"/>
    </div>
  );
}


// App.js outside render()
const map_dispatch_to_props = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    dispatch_log_to_console_function: () => dispatch(log_to_console_function()),
    dispatch_set_donation_amount : (amount) => dispatch(set_donation_amount(amount))
  }
};

export const AppWrapped = connect(map_state_to_props, map_dispatch_to_props)(App);
```

Any idea what the issue might be? My first thought went to missing an import but I can not see anything missing.

Here is the child component

```
// SelectDonation.js (Child component)
import React from "react";
import {css} from "emotion";
import {Button, Modal, Form, Input, Radio} from 'semantic-ui-react';
import store from "../reducer";
export default (props) => {

  const save_donation_amount = (e) => {
    props.dispatch_log_to_console_function();
    props.dispatch_set_donation_amount(e.target.value);
    console.log(store.getState().donation_amount);
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {console.log(props)}
      {console.log(props.ap)}
      <Button
         primary
         onClick={(e) => save_donation_amount(e)}>Next Step
      </Button>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

Comment: can you format your answer correctly? You are providing 3 components, it is not clear on how they relate to each other. In general you have one connect that passes props to the single component. It would be good to see how you are accessing that, but seems that that component is not fully pasted. Also you are using snake case which is not that common for js.

Comment: Done. App.js is the top level component and SelectDonation is the child who is not receiving props through react-redux.

Comment: Nice. as the answer below. The easiest thing to do here, is get SelectDonation connected with `connect`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your child component SelectDonation needs to explicitly receive the dispatch function from App or from Redux in order to use those function. As is, this is not the case. You can pass those function the same way you are passing "Hi" or you could connect SelectDonation to Redux.

I wouldn't recommend either approach. I would recommend your SelectDonation component to notify its parent component when the button was pressed and the parent component would talk to Redux. Check out the official docs for a tutorial on this approach: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html